# How do I move the VALUE in a register to a memory variable in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to move the associated VALUE (not memory address) contained in a register to a memory variable, but it is not working.

```
section .data
        regValue dq 0


section .text
        global main

main:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp
        mov rax, 844
        mov rdi, 9393
        mov [regValue], [rdi]
```

I get error:
 error: operation size not specified

Comment: `mov qword [regValue], 9393` should move the value 9393 directly to memory location of regValue as a 64-bit value. The value to move from (with this method)  can be a signed 32-bit value. The result is sign extended to 64-bits before beign stored at the destination.

Comment: If you want to move a 64-bit value to a memory location you'd have to load the value into a register first and then move it to the destination memory address.

Comment: I need to move the value of various registers into the memory location.

Comment: `mov [regValue], [rdi]` is invalid because no instructions can have 2 explicit memory operands

Comment: If you just want to move the value in a register to an operand then see the answer posted.

Comment: I recommend not adding to the question. If you have a new question start a new question. If the answer here to your original question works for you and answers the question, please consider accepting it as an answer and if you wish upvoting it as well.More on the hows and whys of accepting an answer can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for a start, the *value* of `rdi` is actually `rdi` rather than `[rdi]`. The latter, even assuming it's valid (I'm more of a `gas` man than a `nasm` man), would be the value stored in the memory that `rdi` points to.

And, to specify sizes of operands (where `gas` uses the more succinct `movl/movb/etc` operations), you specify the size *with* the operands, such as:

```
mov qword [regValue], 9393
```

However, I don't think that's *necessary* when you're using a 64-bit register like `rdi` for the source since the size can be inferred from that. I think you can just do:

```
mov [regValue], rdi
```

---

BTW, in NASM you should use `default rel` at the top of your file to prefer RIP-relative addressing modes for static data (like `[regValue]`), instead of 32-bit absolute.

Comment: If the size can be inferred from the source operand it isn't necessary. RDI is a 64-bit register so the destination memory operand will be treated as a QWORD

Comment: Thanks, @Michael, I wan't sure of that since I prefer AT&T notation but I'll defer to your greater knowledge and adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem pax. A note on AT&T syntax: you can leave off the size suffix (on the instruction) if GAS can infer the size from one of the operands. `mov %rdi, regValue` would be the same as `movq %rdi, regValue` . I've already upvoted